# How long does it take to make rabbitmq?

Tags: erlang, rabbitmq, homebrew

I tried installing rabbitmq using homebrew.

I have a MBP i7 and it is just sitting there for the past 5 minutes.

```
brew install rabbitmq
/usr/local/git/bin/git
==> Cloning git://github.com/erlang/otp.git
Updating /Users/bm/Library/Caches/Homebrew/erlang--git
==> Checking out tag OTP_R14B02
==> ./otp_build autoconf
==> ./configure --disable-debug --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/erlang/R14B02 --enable-kernel-poll --enable-threads --enable-dynamic-ssl-lib --enable-smp-support -
==> touch lib/wx/SKIP
==> make
```

This is the second time, the first time I figured it was hung and I cancelled it.

Anyone tried installing it with homebrew?  what could the issue be here?

Comment: Looks like it is building Erlang. It takes some 15-20 minutes here on a Core2Duo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

on my core 2 duo, it took 15.6 minutes to build erlang.

you should see gcc, etc processes and stuff happening in /tmp/homebrew-erlang-*/

Answer (score 1):

On my mcbook pro core duo with 8GB of RAM and SSD it took 20 min. I also killed it once because I thought it was stuck.

```
    Also installing dependencies: erlang
    /usr/local/bin/git
    ==> Cloning https://github.com/erlang/otp.git
    Updating /Users/daviddehghan/Library/Caches/Homebrew/erlang--git
    ==> Checking out tag OTP_R14B03
    ==> ./otp_build autoconf
    ==> ./configure --disable-debug --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/erlang/R14B03 --enable-kernel-poll --enable-threads --enable-dynamic-ssl-lib --enable-smp-s
    ==> touch lib/wx/SKIP
    ==> make
    ==> make install
    ==> Downloading http://erlang.org/download/otp_doc_man_R14B03.tar.gz
    ######################################################################## 100.0%
    ==> Downloading http://erlang.org/download/otp_doc_html_R14B03.tar.gz
    ######################################################################## 100.0%
    /usr/local/Cellar/erlang/R14B03: 6985 files, 260M, built in 20.4 minutes
    ==> Downloading http://www.rabbitmq.com/releases/rabbitmq-server/v2.4.1/rabbitmq-server-2.4.1.tar.gz
    ######################################################################## 100.0%
    ==> Downloading patches
    ######################################################################## 100.0%
    ==> Patching
    patching file Makefile
    Hunk #1 succeeded at 262 (offset -5 lines).
    patching file Makefile
    patching file src/rabbit_networking.erl
    ==> make
    ==> make install
    ==> Caveats
    If this is your first install, automatically load on login with:
        mkdir -p ~/Library/LaunchAgents
        cp /usr/local/Cellar/rabbitmq/2.4.1/com.rabbitmq.rabbitmq-server.plist ~/Library/LaunchAgents/
        launchctl load -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.rabbitmq.rabbitmq-server.plist

    If this is an upgrade and you already have the com.rabbitmq.rabbitmq-server.plist loaded:
        launchctl unload -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.rabbitmq.rabbitmq-server.plist
        cp /usr/local/Cellar/rabbitmq/2.4.1/com.rabbitmq.rabbitmq-server.plist ~/Library/LaunchAgents/
        launchctl load -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.rabbitmq.rabbitmq-server.plist

      To start rabbitmq-server manually:
        rabbitmq-server
    ==> Summary
    /usr/local/Cellar/rabbitmq/2.4.1: 115 files, 1.6M, built in 39 seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

Takes more than 20 minutes, lucky you if you stumble upon this question before you restart the installation :-(